# I can't see containers in docker desktop - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers

So, I have Ubuntu 22.04
I installed Docker desktop and I can't see containers in docker desktop.

What should I do?

Comment: sometimes the docker is stock, try to use docker `CLI` to check if everything is working, the `CLI`can be more helpful than the desktop version,
start with
`> docker ps`
`> docker down`
`> docker up`
**maybe this will help**

Comment: Command Docker down -----   docker: 'down' is not a docker command. Thanks. Anyway, I search a way to repair
 Docker Desktop to see containers in.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried to install docker from the terminal, it will disconnect the daemon from the WSL terminal, or even trying to set up systemd will do.

I suggest to clear data of your WSL, and to reinstall Docker.

This helped for me.